# For Loop Running Multiple Times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-hooks

After running a Graphql query, I am calling a `showUsers` function from `getUserId`which is supposed to display all the users in a styled box.

Currently in my `showUsers`function, even when the `'Number of Users in Loop: ', numberOfUsers` is `1`, I get multiple (3-4) console.logs for the same

```
console.log('Whats the Id', userId);
console.log('UserName', userName);
console.log('LOOP');
```

I don't understand what I am doing wrong. Perhaps something with the useStates?

Here's my full code:

```
export const Page: React.FunctionComponent<PageProps> = ({
  toggleShowPage,
  showAddFriendEmailPage,
}) => {
  const initialValues: FormValues = {
    email: '',
  };

  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('');
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState<UsersLazyQueryHookResult>('');
  const [numberOfUsers, setNumberOfUsers] = useState('');
  const validationSchema = emailValidationSchema;

  useEffect(() => {
    setUserData(userData);
    setNumberOfUsers(numberOfUsers);
  }, [userData, numberOfUsers]);


  const showAlert = () => {
    Alert.alert('Friend Added');
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (showAddFriendEmailPage) return;
    initialValues.email = '';
  }, [showAddFriendEmailPage]);

  const _onLoadUserError = React.useCallback((error: ApolloError) => {
    setErrorMessage(error.message);
    Alert.alert('Unable to Add Friend');
  }, []);

  const [
    createUserRelationMutation,
    {
      data: addingFriendData,
      loading: addingFriendLoading,
      error: addingFriendError,
      called: isMutationCalled,
    },
  ] = useCreateUserRelationMutation({
    onCompleted: (data: CreateUserRelationMutationResult) => {
      showAlert();
    },
  });

   const showUsers = React.useCallback(
     (data: UsersLazyQueryHookResult, numberOfUsers: Number) => {
       for (var i = 0; i < numberOfUsers; i++) {
        console.log('Number of Users in Loop: ', numberOfUsers);
         const userId = data.users.nodes[i].id;
         const userName = ((data.users.nodes[i].firstName).concat(' ')).concat(data.users.nodes[i].lastName);
         console.log('Whats the Id', userId);
         console.log('UserName', userName);
         console.log('Loop');
         return(
           <View style={styles.friends}>
             <View style={styles.item}>
              <Text>{userName}</Text>
             </View>
           </View>
         )
       }      
     },
     [createUserRelationMutation],
   );

  const addFriend = React.useCallback(
    (id: Number) => {
      console.log('Whats the Id', id);
      createUserRelationMutation({
        variables: {
          input: { relatedUserId: id, type: RelationType.Friend, userId: 7 },
        },
      });
    },
    [createUserRelationMutation],
  );

  const getFriendId = React.useCallback(
    (data: UsersLazyQueryHookResult) => {
      if (data) {
        if (data.users.nodes.length == 0) {
          setErrorMessage('User Not Found');
          Alert.alert('User Not Found');
        } else {
          setUserData(data);
          setNumberOfUsers(data.users.nodes.length);
          showUsers(data, Number(numberOfUsers));
          addFriend(Number(data.users.nodes[0].id));
        }
      }
    },
    [addFriend],
  );

  const [loadUsers] = useUsersLazyQuery({
    onCompleted: getFriendId,
    onError: _onLoadUserError,
  });

  const handleSubmitForm = React.useCallback(
    (values: FormValues, helpers: FormikHelpers<FormValues>) => {
      console.log('Submitted');
      loadUsers({
        variables: {
          where: { email: values.email },
        },
      });
      values.email = '';
    },
    [loadUsers],
  );

  return (
    <Modal
      visible={showAddFriendEmailPage}
      animationType="slide"
      transparent={true}>
      <SafeAreaView>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <View style={styles.searchTopContainer}>
              <Formik
                initialValues={initialValues}
                onSubmit={handleSubmitForm}
                validationSchema={validationSchema}>
                {({ handleChange, handleBlur, handleSubmit, values }) => (
                  <View style={styles.searchFieldContainer}>
                    <View style={styles.form}>
                      <FieldInput
                        handleChange={handleChange}
                        handleBlur={handleBlur}
                        value={values.email}
                        fieldType="email"
                      />
                      <ErrorMessage
                        name="email"
                        render={msg => (
                          <Text style={styles.errorText}>{msg}</Text>
                        )}
                      />
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                      <Button
                        rounded
                        style={styles.button}
                        onPress={handleSubmit}>
                        <Text style={styles.text}>Add Friend </Text>
                      </Button>
                    </View>
                  </View>
                )}
              </Formik>
            </View>
            {showUsers(userData, Number(numberOfUsers))}
          </View>
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </Modal>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try logging number of users before the for loop.

Comment: I have tried that too. The output is the same but that's not my concern. My problem is that if the numberOfUsers is 1. Why do I see the logs from the for loop 3 times?

Comment: I would suggest trying to test if numberOfUsers somehow changes throughout the function with console log. I can't really duplicate this problem. Returning in the loop should automatically stop the loop after the first run. Maybe don't return inside the loop.

Comment: If I don't return inside the loop, how can I render all the objects (users)?